# PHP MongoClient Class not found after installation

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using the MongoClient class to access a MongoDB.

```
$mongo = new MongoClient($conset['host'] . ":" . $conset['port'],$conset['host']);
```

I get the fatal error `Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found`  I installed the Mongo client using pear's `pecl install mongo` and then add `extension=mongo.so` to the `php.ini`.  I restart my apache server and check to see if mongo is installed using `pecl search mongo` which returns `mongo   1.5.5 (stable)  1.5.5 MongoDB database driver`

However when I run the same php script it still returns the Fatal error.  Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

**EDIT:**  I just called my VPS host (OVH) and they verified that they do not block any scripts or php extensions.

Comment: Have you checked your apache logs for any errors? I would also check you have added the MongoDB extension to the correct `php.ini` file as there can be several (usually different ones for command line vs apache). Create a simple PHP script with `phpinfo()` and look for the "Configuration File (php.ini) Path".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Stennie's comment I tried some things.  In the end, I stopped my apache2 server, edited the php.ini file, then started (this worked).

I think before, when the apache2 server stopped, the php.ini got overwritten with content so the `extension=mongo.so` was lost.